# How to set navigationsOptions for two tabs and check the routeName to config the different iconNames?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a bottom navigator with `crateBottomNavigator`. It has 2 tabs. The 1st is a `Navigator`, created with `createStackNavigator`. The 2d is a normal screen. 
I use as a second arg the `navigationOptions` and in there the `tabBarIcon`, in order to get the `routeName` and give our tabs a different `icon`, according to: 1) the `routeName` and 2) if it is `focused` or not.

I followed the steps of [React Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html).

The problem is that the icons do not show up!
But, the tabs are functional.

```
// CODE WITH PROBLEM
const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Meals: MealsNavigator,
        Favorites: FavoritesScreen
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;
                if (routeName === 'Meals') {
                    iconName = `restaurant${focused ? '' : '-menu'}`;       
                } else if (routeName === 'Favorites') {
                    iconName = `favorite${focused ? '' : '-border'}`;
                }
                return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            }
        }),

        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }
    }
);
```

**If I separate the screens then it works well.**

```
// CODE WITH NO PROBLEM
const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Meals: {
            screen: MealsNavigator,
            // navigationOptions in config of a navigator, only matter if that
            // navigator is used inside of another navigator.
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                    let iconName = `restaurant${focused ? '' : '-menu'}`;
                    return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                }
            }
        },
        Favorites: {
            screen: FavoritesScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Favorites!',
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                    let iconName = `favorite${focused ? '' : '-border'}`;
                    return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: Colors.active,
            inactiveColor: Colors.inactive
        }
    }
);
```

Here is the whole module.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';


const MealsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Categories: {
            screen: CategoriesScreen
        },
        CategoryMeals: {
            screen: CategoryMealsScreen
        },
        MealDetail: MealDetailScreen
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : ''
            },
            headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor,
            headerTitle: 'A Screen'
        }
    }
);

const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Meals: MealsNavigator,
        Favorites: FavoritesScreen
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                let iconName;
                if (routeName === 'Meals') {
                    iconName = `restaurant${focused ? '' : '-menu'}`;       
                } else if (routeName === 'Favorites') {
                    iconName = `favorite${focused ? '' : '-border'}`;
                }
                return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
            }
        }),

        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'tomato',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(MealsFavTabNavigator);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Do the icons appear if you try putting in a static string like `name={"favorite-border"}`

Comment: @Auticcat, Unfortunately No! Thanks though ;)

Comment: I tuoni that the problem is that you’re using navigationOptions instead of defaultNavigationOptions, try changing that

Comment: @Auticcat You got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured it out through the comments, I'll write it as definitive answer here.

The problem is that navigationOptions, as parameter in `createBottomTabNavigator`, doesn't have a tabBarIcon key usable to specify a specific tab icon.

To do that, you need to pass it as parameter inside `defaultNavigationOptions`, used to specify standard options for every item of the navigator, such as tabBarIcon.

Answer (score 0):

Further, I wanted to change the icons and the color, but the icons where all from different sets. 
This is with what I finally came up.

```
defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                        // Ionicons = ios-book
                        // MaterialCommunityIcons = book
                        // FontAwesome = cross
                        // FontAwesome5 = bolnisi-cross
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
                            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
                            let iconName = '';
                            if (routeName === 'Books') {
                                iconName = focused ? 'ios-book' : 'book';
                            } else if (routeName === 'Favorites') {
                                iconName = focused ? 'bolnisi-cross' : 'cross';
                            }
                            // For Books
                            if (routeName === 'Books' && focused) {
                                return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                                // For Favorites
                            } else if (routeName === 'Favorites' && focused) {
                                return <MaterialCommunityIcons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                            }
                            // For Books
                            if (routeName === 'Books' && !focused) {
                                return <FontAwesome name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                                // For Favorites
                            } else if (routeName === 'Favorites' && !focused) {
                                return <FontAwesome5 name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
                            }
                        }
                    }),
```